# Apply function for counting length of a DataFrame filter

Tags: pandas

What's the best way to create a new pandas column with the length of filtering of another df based on a value from the first df?

`df_account` has account numbers

`df_retention` has rows for each date an account numbers was active

I am trying to create a new column on `df_account` that has the total number of days the account was active. Using `.apply` seems extremely slow.

```
def retention_count(x):
    return len(df_retention[df_retention['account'] == x])

df_account['retention_total'] = df_account['account'].apply(retention_count)
```

On a small number of rows, this works, but when my `df_account` has over 750k rows it is really slow. What can I do to make this faster? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use groupby and count the rows in the df_retention dataframe. Assuming `account` is your index on df_account

```
df_account.set_index('account',inplace=True)
df_account['retention_total'] = df_retention.groupby('account').count()
```

Comment: Ah hah! Thank you kindly. Groupby is loads faster.